# How to continue execution of code only when windows service is completed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, named-pipes

I have a Windows service which performs a fairly long running task. At the moment, I spawn a new thread, which executes a method which goes off and calls this windows service. This code looks like:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExecyuteLongRunningMethod));
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

Higher up in the callstack (when this code is done), a message box popups stating the result of the operation.

However, while this block of code executes (`ExecuteLongRunningMethod` calls the windows svc), a message box popups stating that nothing has changed as a result of the operation, but because this is before the code block above has completed, the wrong message box appears.

Thus, the question is, what would be the proper way to only continue execution in the winforms app (this is what calls the windows svc), ONLY when the windows service is finished? I am thinking that the approach above is incorrect as the thread will call the windows service (another process), so while the windows service does its stuff, my code (winforms app) will continue. Either some sort of signaling is required, or something like named pipes?

The app is in .NET 3.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose the status of your service execution via a WCF API and call it using netTcp or named pipes, you could poll the service or use a WCF CallBack.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a BackgroundWorker, so you can set an event for its completion?
In Backgroundworker running method you can run the service and wait for a manual reset event (for example) or a mutex and, when received this you can exit main method.
So OnCompleted event is raised in your main thread (UI for example) and the job is done...

In your app add a Backgroundworker and name it `bgw`.
Then you can do:

```
private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // 1. Run the service
    // 2. Wait for mutex
}

private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here you can handle the end of the service
    // and return the status in main thread
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that. How would this work? I mean, the windows service would need to raise some sort of signal so that the winforms app knows it completed.

Comment: So I won't need to modify the windows svc? I'll give this a go.

Comment: @dotnetdev: you have to modify the svc in this way: when you run it, it must create (or take ownership) of a mutex `mut` and release it when finish its work. Mutex `mut` is the one you wait in your backgroundworker...

Comment: Your creating a tight coupling between the service and the client when there is no need to do so.

Comment: @Llloyd: imho service is not coupled to anything: it runs creating and releasing a mutex, stop. Client is coupled to service, but this is a choice. Am I wrong? :)

Comment: In my scenario, this isn't too much of a concern. @Marco: For the mutex, should the first param (initiallyowned) be true or false?

Comment: @dotnetdev: in service, parameter `initiallyowned` must be true, so service gets ownership of mutex and releases it when exiting. In this way client can only wait for service to end before taking mutex ownership.

Comment: @dotnetdev: I know for you this is not a concern: you've just accepted my answer!! :) But someone gave me -1 and I don't understand the reason... Never mind: it's important that I solved your trouble... at the end we're here to give and receive good help :)

Comment: Just as I thought. I've made a mutex in the service, importantly giving it a descriptive name and, as you confirmed, set initiallyOwned to true. In my winforms app, I've called Mutex.OpenExisting(Name) and then called WaitOne() on the mutex and then Release(). Is there anything wrong with that logic? Thanks for your help. The -1 may be due to the elegance of the solution but I don't see a problem with the solution you've posted. This is a small app so I don't have to use the most complex methodology to achieve this (e.g. WCF).

Comment: @dotnetdev: no, it's perfect! Remember to start service before calling `mutex.WaitOne()`, otherwise mutex does not exists.

Comment: Yeah that is the case. The service is started in service manager, at the top of the method before the long-running logic, the mutex is created, the main code runs, and that is it. Then the rest is in the winforms app. So there is nothing to do with the mutex apart from create it in the svc? Also, is the reason you posted the background worker only because the code is long running or is there another reason?

Comment: @dotnetdev: No, there is nothing else to do in svc. I used a backgroundworker because it can easily interact with your UI (form) and has `DoWork` and `Completed` events that makes life easier compared to a normal thread.

Comment: True. Thanks. I'm still modifying the code (other bits too), but I believe that the backgroundworker can be used for a long running task (Calling the svc) + updating the progress bar in the winforms ui with no freezing of the ui, right? (That's where my code is heading).

Comment: @dotnetdev: exactly, this is the main reason of using a bgw, leaving main thread (UI) free and let user use it without freeze

Comment: One issue: When I call Mutex.OpenExisting(Name), I get an exception (no handle of given name could be found).

Comment: @dotnetdev: Are you using Windows Seven? Service runs under which account?

Comment: Yes, Windows Seven. Service is running under LocalSystem account.

Comment: @dotnetdev: I don't remember well, but I think it could be something about isolation. Check MS documentation for mutexes under Seven; maybe you have to pass the name of the session, but I can be wrong...

Comment: @dotnetdev: are you really sure that your service is started and the mutex has already been created when you execute `mutex.OpenExisting(Name)`?

Comment: @dotnetdev: another question? Why do you need to run a service to execute a long time operation? Can't you simply execute the same action in backgroundworker? If you really need the service, check my previous comment.

Comment: Hi, I need the service as actions otherwise requiring admin permissions for client users is performed in it. The mutex is created, as I've stepped through the svc, past the line where the mutex is constructed.

Comment: @dotnetdev: try to put "Global\" in front of your mutex name and try again. You can take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) and [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/mutex-and-windows-services-t1226374.html) to have further infos to work with. Let me know if you solve this last part...

Comment: The windows svc and app are in the same security context. Are you sure that releasemutex is not required in the service?

Comment: @dotnetdev: oh yes, certainly!! When svc is created it must call `CreateMutex` and when it's going to finish (or stopped) it must call `ReleaseMutex`. If svc doesn't call `ReleaseMutex` your client remains waiting with `mutex.WaitOne()`...